# scala type conversion using implicit -> enforce type checks

Tags: scala, sbt

Here is simple bit of code and question related.

Is there a way to tell scala compiler that if type to which this conversion will be applied to not exists than error on compilation time!

I can see a warning in the sbt tool but can't see any description so war.

```
class A(val n: Int) {
    def +(other: A) = new A(n + other.n)
}

object A {
    implicit def fromMyInt(n: Int) = new A(n)
}

val r = 1 + new A(1)

println( r )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scala compiler already does this.

Here's a sample file, `test.scala`, that attempts an unavailable implicit conversion:

```
class A(val n: Int) {
  def +(other: A) = new A(n + other.n)
}

object A {
  implicit def fromMyInt(n: Int) = new A(n)

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(1 + new A(1))
    println(1.0 + new A(1))
  }
}
```

Trying to compile this gives an error:

```
➤ scalac test.scala
test.scala:10: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Double <and>
  (x: Long)Double <and>
  (x: Int)Double <and>
  (x: Char)Double <and>
  (x: Short)Double <and>
  (x: Byte)Double <and>
  (x: String)String
 cannot be applied to (A)
    println(1.0 + new A(1))
                ^
one error found
```

Comment: Well, can't see this error in sbt tool. But I know what you mean: run it like : scalac -feature main.scala  .. and then I have a error. Thanks, This will do!